# Rails 3.0 - Where to put this logic?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I've got a Model Task with a member due_date.  I'm using [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) to take natural language input from the user and convert it to a Time, which then gets saved to the model.

I'm just not sure the best Rails, MVC-ish way to handle these use cases:

1. Display a formatted string (with some logic involved) to the user every time I show Task.due_date
2. Allow the user to input plaintext and have it parsed automagically everywhere they can edit Task.due_date

A helper method to format time was my first idea, like this:

```
<%= format_time task.due_date %>
```

combined with an overloaded setter on an accessor in my Task model, like this:

```
attr_accessor :due_date_string

def due_date_string=(string)
  self.due_date = Chronic.parse(string)
end
```

This works everywhere I want it to *except* in my forms for editing:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :due_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :due_date_string %>
</div>
```

I don't know how to make the f.text_field element 'wire up' properly so that it saves to :due_date_string, but uses the helper method to display the string.

I don't necessarily need specific code examples, just looking for the kind of pattern that pro Rails-ers would use here.

Thanks!

Comment: so you need to be able to allow user input something like "7 days from now", then parse and save it it DateTime?

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  Chronic takes care of the actual parsing of the string to the DateTime for me, I just need to know where to put the logic for translating to/from these strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With according to MVC conventions, data handle is about Model layer responsibility.
So you are going in right direction to do a setter (wrapper for due_date attribute):

You need to check that is attr_acessible that is access to get a data from params

```
def due_date_string=(string)
  self.due_date = Chronic.parse(string) || Date.today
end
```

The representation logic to show the parsed date is Helper layer responsibility

Comment: This works great for inputting the value, and I can use my helper method for displaying it on indexes and such.  What I don't know how to do, with this solution, is to prepopulate editing fields with a formatted string representation of the date.  Any ideas there?

Comment: you can try to use default value for **text_field** *:value => format_time(Date.today)*

Answer (score 1):

In order to use:

```
f.text_field :due_date_string
```

Don't you also need a getter for the new attribute? e.g.,

```
def due_date_string
  format_time self.due_date
end
```

Perhaps share what error or failure occurs when you use the custom text field. :)

Comment: This does work, interpreter-wise, but this is where I run into design issues.  My format_time method has to know about the current time zone I'm working with, and is used for other times in other models as well, so it seems to clearly belong in a view helper.  In order to use it in the model itself (the code you show is exactly what I had, in fact), wouldn't I need this logic accesible in the Model? If that's possible cleanly, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I apologize I'm probably missing something in the problem you're describing. But if you are defining a new attribute (due_date_string in this case) it should be completely defined in the model. So both the due_date_string reader and the due_date_string= writer should be in your model rb file (if they're not already).